# Display returned value as text for label field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a function that is returning a value of type String, I need to call that function and display value inside a text field as below

The function is:

```
Public Function getemailaddress() As String
```

Label is:

```
<asp:Label Text='<% HERE I NEED TO CALL THE FUNCTION AND SHOW RETURNED
VALUE  %>' runat="server" ID="EmailAddress2" />
```

That Label is placed inside a Datalist, and I don't have an access to the code behind.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't have an access to code behind?

Comment: @ZakiMohammed, it is web forms project and it is compiled already, I can only write embedded codes within the aspx page.

Comment: Then how can you able to recompile the code even if you write embedded code directly in aspx page. Any how you need to be compiled

Comment: I don't need to recompile the code @ZakiMohammed, the function is written inside <% %> tags!

Comment: Have you tried using "ItemDataBound" method of DataList?

Answer (score 1):

I have made following code as per your current scenario where I am assuming you are getting your data filled in DataList from the code behind while your method and label changing code is in .aspx file

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="ms_temp._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">

        <asp:DataList ID="lv" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lv_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

    </form>

</body>
</html>

<script runat="server">

    Function GetEmailAddress(name As String) As String
        Return name & "@gmail.com"
    End Function

    Protected Sub lv_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As DataListItemEventArgs)

        Dim lbl As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblName")
        Dim name As String = e.Item.DataItem

        lbl.Text = name & ": " & GetEmailAddress(name)

    End Sub

</script>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim list = New List(Of String) From {"John", "Allen", "William"}
        lv.DataSource = list
        lv.DataBind()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Output

```
John: John@gmail.com
Allen: Allen@gmail.com
William: William@gmail.com
```

The DataList "lv" is getting filled on the page load with some random names.

I have made "GetEmailAddress" method which you want to call on a in order to change the label's text of DataList. This method is getting called on "lv_ItemDataBound" event and changing the value of label.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, your example helped me a lot.